# Python remove row if cell value in dataframe contain characters less than 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe like I am trying to keep rows that have more than 5 characters. Here is what I tried, but it removes 'of', 'U.', 'and','Arts',...etc. I just need to remove characters in a row that have len less than 5.

```
id schools
1  University of Hawaii
2  Dept in Colorado U.
3  Dept
4  College of Arts and Science
5  Dept
6  Bldg
```

wrong output from my code:

```
0    University Hawaii
1             Colorado
2                     
3      College Science
4                     
5
```

Looking for output like this:

```
id schools
1  University of Hawaii
2  Dept in Colorado U.
4  College of Arts and Science
```

Code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s = ['University of Hawaii', 'Dept in Colorado U.','Dept','College of Arts and Science','Dept','Bldg']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':l, 'schools':s})
df1 = df1['schools'].str.findall('\w{5,}').str.join(' ') # not working
df1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regex is a huge (and slow) overkill for this task. You can use simple pandas indexing:

```
filtrered_df = df1[df1['schools'].str.len() > 5]  # or >= depending on the required logic
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler filter for your data.

```
 mask = df1['schools'].str.len() > 5
```

Then create a new data frame from the filter

```
df2 = df1[mask].copy()
```

Comment: `df2` will contain all rows where `schools` length is <= 5 which is the opposite of what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Right you are. I incorrectly added the ~ operator. I went ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
name = ['University of Hawaii','Dept in Colorado U.','Dept','College of Arts and Science','Dept','Bldg']

labels =['schools']
df =pd.DataFrame.from_records([[i] for i in name],columns=labels)
df[df['schools'].str.len() >5 ]
```